# How to access controls inside DataRepeater

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

I have 2 textBoxes inside WinForms DataRepeater ([Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx)) and a button

When the button is clicked, I want to access these textBoxes

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dataRepeater1.CurrentItem.Controls["TextBox1"].Text
```