# set tooltip for a control inside dataRepeater

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, datarepeater

I have a pictureBox inside a Winforms DataRepeater for which I want to set the tooltip, I tried

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.SetToolTip(dataRepeater1.ItemTemplate.Controls["picDeleteEntry"]
                                                       ,"Delete This Entry");
```

I also tried

```
tt.SetToolTip(picDeleteEntry, "Delete This Entry");
```

still its not showing tooltip.

How to solve?

Comment: I think you will have to loop through each DataRepeaterItem and then set the tooltip using 'Controls` collection. (Is this a different control didn't find anything such in winform) like [`dataRepeater1.CurrentItem.Controls["TextBox1"]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029053/how-to-access-controls-inside-datarepeater)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: `Is this a different control didn't find anything such in winform` I didn't get what you meant

Comment: I meant `DataRepeater` not available in the toolbox, unless you are in VS2010

Comment: @V4Vendetta: its under `Visual Basic powerPack`.. right click on your toolbox > `Choose Items` > select `DataRepeater` under >NET Framework Components.. its better to create a new Tab `Visual Basic PowerPack` and place the control inside

Comment: @V4Vendetta: ya, I am using VS2010 and VS version is not the issue I am talking about..

Comment: Did you try looping through, plz see the link i mentioned previously if it helps

Comment: @V4Vendetta: looping through is not desirable or not proper way of achieving this especially when DataRepeater has too many repeater items.. I think the answer I posted below is better than looping through..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I arrived at a solution, but let me know if any still better solution is available

**my idea is like this:**

in mouseHover event of the PictureBox inside DataRepeater, set the tooltip like this

```
if (tt.GetToolTip((PictureBox)sender)==string.Empty)
    tt.SetToolTip((PictureBox)sender, "Delete This Entry");
```